# Error in django 1.8.7 version with python 2.7.12

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, ubuntu, django-models

I am getting the following trackback error message when I run command(python3 manage.py runserver) on ubuntu OS:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
```

I am using the following version of django and python:

- Django 1.8.7
- python: 2.7.12

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue? Because I tried it 10 times from google suggestion but didn't get the right answer.

Comment: Wrong python version... Try `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: @doriclazar thanks for reply but I am still getting the same error with run "python manage.py runserver "